# npm cannot install some packages globally and locally?

Tags: npm, package, node-modules

I'm developing some JavaScript application with VSCode editor, and it says cannot find ESlint package. So i tried install it locally on app directory and globally, but both methods are failed. It gives following error(log file) and stops installation.

> #### silly fetchPackageMetaData error for emoji-regex@^7.0.1 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gex-7.0.1.tgz","fileC'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to install package that causes the error and it also get failed, i cleared cache of npm with `npm cache clean --force` and re-install `eslint` package. And it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" before answering a question. Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: In particular, is this an answer, or additional information for your question? (You can edit your question to add further information.)